# Is there a way to add list in a django model class?

Tags: python, django, list, django-models, django-apps

I'm a django beginner and trying to make a project from scratch.
My models are :

```
class Citizen(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=False)
    citizen_id = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} by {}'.format(self.name, self.citizen_id)


class Manager(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=False)
    manager_id = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} by {}'.format(self.name, self.manager_id)


class Message(models.Model):
    sender = models.ForeignKey(Citizen, Manager, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='sender')
    receiver = models.ForeignKey(Citizen, Manager, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='receiver')
    message = models.CharField(max_length=1200)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_read = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.message

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('timestamp',)


class Centre(models.Model):
    pass
```

In Centre , there's gonna be one manager and then a lot of citizens. What should I do here? Should I add a list of citizens? Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think reading [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/) might help.

But essentially you'd want to implement what's called a One (Centre) to Many (Citizen) relationship. In short your citizen can have a [Foreign Key](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/7272/foreign-key#:%7E:text=A%20foreign%20key%20is%20a,establishing%20a%20link%20between%20them.) called `centre_id` which will be the id of the centre they belong to. And then you can use the id of the Centre to [query](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/introduction-to-queries-mysql) a list of citizens, or if you want to fetch the centre and attach a list of it's citizens to it, then you can do something which is called a [join](https://django.fun/docs/django-orm-cookbook/en/2.0/join/)

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this in two different ways:

1. Set a ForeignKey field on your citizen model. This is a many-to-one relationship meaning that one Centre can have many Citizens. You can set the Centre on the Citizen object, the centre can be accessed as `citizen.centre` and in verse as `centre.citizen_set.all()`

```
class Citizen(models.Model):
    ...
    centre = models.ForeignKey(Centre, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

2. If there is only one Manager per Centre then you can use a OneToOneField to ensure that there aren't multiple managers. It works differently to a many-to-one relationship as it is completely two-way, e.g. `manager.centre` and `centre.manager`.

```py
class Manager(models.Model):
    ...
    centre = models.OneToOneField(Centre, ...
```